# How to create users like students and professors on MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a newbie with PHP and MySQL. My project is about creating a website online on which I can put my school friend's grades and manage them. The problem is that I don't know how to separate users students/teachers.

I got an idea but still not clear. If in login page a make a radio button and add on it like this: "Student or Teacher". If they choose teacher I must test teacher's accounts to login in them to midify page.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into the user/group/role pattern.   You'll enter individuals into groups and assign roles to groups. You'll have to decide if you want one role per individual or many.